# Google test framework - Dependency between test cases

Tags: c++, testing, frameworks

I am new to using Google test framework and still going through lot of materials to utilize it to full extent.

Is there any way I can dictate/specify a relation between test cases so that it can be executed conditionally? Like lets say I have two tests; Can I run the second test only if the first succeeds? I am not really sure if it falls under the original rule of testing 'units' but was just wondering if its possible.

Comment: Did you just create the "conditionaltestcases" tag? The question is pretty interesting because it gets into the design of testing frameworks, but as you muse, such a thing really does violate testing best practices.  Tests are supposed to be independent.  I'm not sure we need that tag just for this one question, though.

Comment: yeah I figured this is actually not 'unit' testing as I stated in question itself; but like i said was just wondering. I removed the tag; did not know it creates one if its not there; was just trying to be more specific

Comment: That's fine, it's still a good question.  I don't know the answer, but hopefully someone else will.  You can simulate what you are trying to do, perhaps, with multiple asserts within the same test case in order to try one assert if a previous one fails.  I know that is not an exact answer to your question, which was on the test case level, but it might be close.  It is also not a good practice, but is of theoretical interest.

Comment: @RayToal i've implemented dependencies in my unit testing lib (which i intend on making open source one day). i find it very useful. i don't think it violates "testing best practices" -- dependencies are critical to software components. for example, when you have large dependencies, it's helpful to simply say "Library B requires Library A, so ensure Library A also passes its tests". to say it violates best practices is like saying black box testing is the only effective means to test -- but black box testing only gives so much coverage and is impractical to test thoroughly at this perspective.

Comment: I thought the OP was talking about dependencies between unit test cases rather than dependencies between libraries.  If you are talking about integration tests then yes you look at dependencies between components.  For unit tests, you should be able to run them in any order whatsoever, and you run them all, and you run them quickly (if they are built right).

Comment: @RayToal *I thought the OP was talking about dependencies between unit test cases rather than dependencies between libraries.* yes, that is also the impression i had. library dependencies were just the obvious example. classes in a library can have similar dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

There no way to do it in source. Possible solution use shell scripts and run tests using filter.

Python example:

```
from subprocess import call

def runTest(pattern):
    return call(['test', '--gtest_filter=%s' % pattern])

if runTest('FirstPriorityTestPattern') == 0:
   return runTest('SecondPriorityTestPattern')
return 1
```